# Using wstring for swprintf_s instead of wchar_t *

Tags: c++, wstring

How can i use `std::wstring` variable as argument in to `swprintf_s` instead `wchar_t *`?

My code is as below but has error:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    std::wstring     msg(20, 0);
    swprintf_s( msg.c_str(), 20, L"This is a test for using std::wstring");//this line has error

 wcout<< msg<< endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Error (active)no instance of overloaded function "swprintf_s" matches the argument list

Comment: You can not do this directly because the underlying buffer isn't meant to be written to.  Other fields in the string object don't get correctly updated (like length) even if you force it with creative casting causing weird errors to manifest later.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string 
The signature for std::wstring::c_str is "const wchar_t * c_str() const;" that means it returns a "const wchar_t *" while swprintf_s wants a "wchar_t *".  So you should look at a different way to do this.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

`swprintf` or `swprintf_s` writes to the memory pointed by its first parameter. Therefore that parameter cannot be a `const` char or wchar pointer. But the return value of std::wstring::c_str() is `const char*` .  So you cannot just cast way the `const`. As mentioned by Jason, if you break the rule, wstring::size() may not return the right value.

What you can do is

```
wchar_t buffer[20];

swprintf_s(buffer, 20, L"This is a test for using std::wstring");
```

If you want a std::wstring, you can just use the constructor, like wstring `msg(buffer)`.

Comment: "So you cannot just cast way the 'const'." -- You can, as of C++11. `msg.c_str()` is guaranteed to be the same as `&msg[0]` (provided the string is non-empty).

Comment: @hvd you are technically correct, but the string.length() will not be updated.

Comment: @CS Pei There is a syntax error in your solution. `wchar_t * buffer[20];` should be changed to `wchar_t buffer[20];` as we don't need pointer to array

Comment: Thanks. you are right. fixed